# Get posts with multiple meta values

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, get-posts, meta-query

I have a ACF select field which takes multiple value. Now I want to use `get_posts()` to get those custom posts. My arguments look like this:

```
$party = 'test1';
$function = 'test1, test2';
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'party',
            'compare'   => '=',
            'value'     => $party,
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'function',
            'compare'   => 'IN',
            'value'     => array($function),
        )
    )
);
$items = get_posts($args);
```

But this does not work! Don't know what is wrong here!

Comment: Why you don't try with: `$items = new WP_Query( $args );` [WP_Query Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: What are the types of these ACF fields?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way which you have clled for ACF.

**Parameters**

```
<?php $field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value); ?>
```

- $field_name: the name of the field to be retrieved. eg “page_content” (required)
- $post_id: Specific post ID where your value was entered. Defaults to current post ID (not required). This can also be options / taxonomies / users / etc
- $format_value: whether or not to format the value loaded from the db. Defaults to true (not required).

**Usage**

Get a value from the current post

```
$value = get_field( "text_field" );
```

Get a value from a specific post

```
$value = get_field( "text_field", 123 );
```

**Check if value exists**

```
$value = get_field( "text_field" );

if( $value ) {

    echo $value;

} else {

    echo 'empty';

}
```

Get a value from other places

```
$post_id = null; // current post
$post_id = 1;
$post_id = "option";
$post_id = "options"; // same as above
$post_id = "category_2"; // target a specific category
$post_id = "event_3"; // target a specific taxonomy (this tax is called "event")
$post_id = "user_1"; // target a specific user (user id = 1)

$value = get_field( "text_field", $post_id );
```

**Get a value without formatting**

In this example, the field `image` is an image field which would normally return an Image object.
However, by passing false as a 3rd parameter to the get_field function, the value is never formatted and returned as is from the Database.

Please note the second parameter is set to `false` to target the current post

```
$image = get_field('image', false, false);
```

Comment: Did you at all understand my question ?? !! :D

Comment: you use ACF plugin and not able to fetch its value. is this your question?

Comment: Not really. A baby can do that. If you read my question carefully you will understand :)

Comment: Did you pass 'category' => $id ??